# How do I resize a UIImageView in the '.m'

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a UIImageView that I want to resize when you press a button. I haven't been able to find any on other forums or sources.

Any help appreciated,

user826671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a sample using slider control.
You can activate this slider on your button press and use it to increase or decrease the size of the images
https://github.com/manishnath/Code/tree/master/zommin

Answer (score 4):

Let me google it for you http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Answer (score 2):

-(void) onButtonClick
 {
     CGRect frameRect = temp.frame; //temp ur UIMAGEVIEW

```
 frameRect.size.width= your_width;

 frameRect.size.height= height;

 temp.frame=frameRect;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If its about UIImage, you can do it by this way. For UIImageView you can change its frame size.

```
- (UIImage *) resizeImage:(UIImage *)image newWidth:(CGFloat)width 
              newHeight: (CGFloat)height 
{
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, width,height);
    CGSize size = area.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);  
    [image drawInRect:area];    
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize the image view itself, do like

```
CGRect newRect = imageView.frame;
newRect.size.width = reqWidth;
newRect.size.height = reqHeight;
imageView.frame = newRect;
```

The image will also be resized if the imageview has the `contentMode` property `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.